# Нужна ли запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, интонация

Хочется поставить запятую, правильно ли это будет?

*Разве её забудешь, вот она (?) пришла.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая разговорная фраза дает возможность использовать разные варианты пунктуации. Пишущий, добиваясь максимально выразить смысл, подчеркнуть логические акценты, паузы и эмоции, может быть свободен. Но даже не имея контекста, для меня является очевидным наличие паузы во второй части и, соответственно, графическое ее выделение.

*Разве её забудешь! Вот она, пришла.

Разве её забудешь? Вот она – пришла.

Разве её забудешь: вот она, пришла.

Разве её забудешь: вот она – пришла.*

Как видите, мои варианты заменяют первую запятую на другие знаки, которые четче выражают отношения между двумя частями. А дальше запятая или тире выполняют одинаковую функцию (больше присоединительную), только по-разному обозначая длительность паузы и интонацию.

Каждый из этих и других способов оформления замысла не идет в разрез с правилами.